# Is there a way to request a specific webview version for excel add-ins?

Tags: office-js

While testing our excel add-ins we came across a user that uninstalled IE 11 from his Windows 10 machine, Microsoft Edge was installed and working fine.  When we try to load any add-in the following error is displayed:

[image: Error Message when IE is missing]

Is there a way to ask Excel to use an edge webview to avoid this issue?

Otherwise, are there any plans to bundle the webview with excel so it doesn't depend on the host's browser? (I would strongly suggest to use a chromium webview)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will pass along the suggestion to the team -- but at the moment, no, Add-ins on a PC version of Office will make use of the system's installed Internet Explorer.  And Add-ins do not currently support the Edge browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think bundling the web view with the office products would solve this issue and also would create a better dev environment by introducing consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the feedback. I am from the Office add-ins development team and I would like to clarify the answer here a little bit.

Currently, the Office add-in framework depends on Internet Explorer system control in Windows, so we can't easily swap that out with another web control. Office add-in users will need to install Internet Explorer 11 (or IE9 or above on down level Windows) for the add-ins to work. However, the users can keep their browser of choice as the default browser and continue to use that browser.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My concern with the current approach would be that it greatly diminishes the possibilities of add-ins. Allowing the add-ins to run in browsers as old as IE9 and IE10 would mean that we, developers, couldn't make use of most new technologies. Can we at least make IE11 a requirement? It is still not the ideal environment for development but it is light years ahead of its older iterations.

Comment: @Dario , I think I remember seeing that IE 11 is the minimum requirement for Office 2016, or at least for Office 365.  So I think actual real-world add-in users with just IE 9 or 10 are very very few.  If you rely on functionality that only IE 11 supports, I think it's reasonable to use browser detection on add-in startup and block an older IE version (I intend to do just that for a store-bound add-in that I am working on).  You might just need to include it as a note, with a justification, when submitting the add-in into the Store.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE MAY 2019**

Microsoft has now removed IE11 from the webview and replaced with MS Edge. You will need to ensure you have both the Windows 10 version and Office Version as per the link below

See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/